# How to get bootstrap helpers using Rails 5 and Bootstrap 4

Tags: asset-pipeline, erb, helper, ruby-on-rails-5, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm working on an application upgrade from rails 4.2 (with bootstrap 3) to rails 5 (bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha3.1).
I'm using the official `bootstrap-rubygem` https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem and I'm following the steps on the documentation, but the problem I have is the absence of the classical bootstrap helpers. I.e.: menu_group, nav_bar, menu_item, dropdown_divider, etc...

Is there any way to get these helpers back as on bootstrap3?

The relevant configuration I have, regarding this issue, is:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3.1'
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is due to bootstrap framework has large number of changes.**